# Android Java SVG залить по тапу форму цветом под пальцем

Tags: java, android, svg, drawable

Возникла не сложная, но непонятная для меня проблема. Возможно, данный вопрос уже подымался, что было бы очевидно, но ответа я не нашел.

Есть векторное изображение (SVG), которое мы конвертируем в xml и в последующем отображаем его в `ImageView`. Вопрос заключается в том, как по тапу я могу поставить нужному мне `<path>,` атрибут `fillColor` из java-кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может что то типа такого:

```
DrawableCompat.setTint(imageView.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourColor));
```

или такого:

```
public class TintIcon {

    private static int[][] states = new int[][] {
            new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed},
            new int[] { android.R.attr.state_focused},
            new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected},
            new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_selected}
    };

    private static int[] colors = new int[] {
            Color.parseColor("#4EA62E"), // primary color
            Color.parseColor("#4EA62E"), // primary color
            Color.parseColor("#4EA62E"), // primary color
            Color.parseColor("#868686")  // grey icon
    };

    private static int[] colorsSwitch = new int[] {
            Color.parseColor("#D7B00F"), // yellow color
            Color.parseColor("#D7B00F"), // yellow color
            Color.parseColor("#D7B00F"), // yellow color
            Color.parseColor("#868686")  // grey icon////
    };

    private static ColorStateList myColorStateList = new ColorStateList(states,colors);
    private static ColorStateList myColorStateListSwitch = new ColorStateList(states,colorsSwitch);

    public static Drawable tintIconToGreenColor(Context context, Drawable icon) {
        if (icon != null) {
            icon = DrawableCompat.wrap(icon).mutate();
            DrawableCompat.setTintList(icon, myColorStateList );
            DrawableCompat.setTintMode(icon, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
        return icon;
    }

    public static Drawable tintIconYellowColor(Context context, Drawable icon) {
        if (icon != null) {
            icon = DrawableCompat.wrap(icon).mutate();
            DrawableCompat.setTintList(icon, myColorStateListSwitch );
            DrawableCompat.setTintMode(icon, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
        return icon;
    }   
}
```

Этих два метода `tintIconToGreenColor` и `tintIconYellowColor` красать иконку в зеленый и желтый цвет. Я его использую что бы на серой иконке менять цвет заливки рисунка.

Вот такую иконку в `.png` я крашу в два разных цвета:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Он заливает полностью, но вот, каким образом, в таком случае обращаться непосредственно к "<path>" ?

Comment: тогда хз, гляньте тут, может поможет чем то. Вам принципиально svg использовать?

Comment: В принципе нет, не принципиально. Задача состоит в том, чтобы закрасить фигуру по тапу, нужным мне цветом, при условии, что цвет заранее не известен и количество фигур на картинке тоже.

Comment: @СергейНейкович Я обновил ответ